# How can I search into two models from a separated view? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, activerecord

I have nested models "Clients" and "Packages" and a view called "Dashboard" I want implement a search form for searching packages and the results of a query shows into a Dashboard view.

How can I do that? Here is my project models

**Models:**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :packages, dependent: :destroy
end

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

**Partial form Dashboard:**

```
<!-- Search Form -->
<div class="row search">
  <div class="col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <%= form_tag client_packages_path(:client_id => :id), :method => "get" do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search package barcodes" %>
    </p>
    <p class="pull-right">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ./Search -->
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'dashboard#index'
  get 'dashboard/index'

  devise_for :users
  resources :clients do
    resources :packages
  end

end
```

**Rake Routes**

[image: routes]

Thanks in advance

Comment: you said: 'the results of a query shows into a Dashboard view' but the form goes to: client_packages_path not the dashboard path. Can you clarify why you did that ?

Comment: Please post text, not images :)

Answer (score 0):

I think for this goals will be enough to make 2 scopes like

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :packages, dependent: :destroy
  scope :foo, ->(criteria){where('some=?',criteria)}
end

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
scope :bar, ->(criteria){where('some=?',criteria)}
end

#in view

Package.bar('lookup') + Client.foo('other lookup')
```

There are more elegant solutions, but this one will be good enough for low-mid load